# How to compacting anything not null in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my input

```
code    US    UK    Germany   Japan
AR5      13   NaN         7    NaN
A85     NaN     9       NaN      8
```

Here's my Output, anything not null will be registered

```
code  country
A85       UK
A85    Japan
AR5       US
AR5   Germany
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can melt then `dropna`:

```
df.melt('code', var_name='Country').dropna()
```

Output:

```
  code  Country  value
0  AR5       US   13.0
3  A85       UK    9.0
4  AR5  Germany    7.0
7  A85    Japan    8.0
```